# NPE When Accessing TextView on a Fragment after instantiation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android.

I have read through the threads and tried various solutions but none worked for me.  Here is what I have which works.

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

TextView mTextView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    mTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView1);
    mTextView.setText("This works"); //This works fine
    return rootView;
}
```

}

This will update the TextView just fine with the words "This works".

But when I try this to make it more flexible so I can update it while the app is running, it fails on me with this error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.schoolproject.tabs.Tab1.changeText(Tab1.java:29)

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

TextView mTextView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    mTextView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView1);
    return rootView;
}

public void changeText(String mText) {
    mTextView.setText(mText);
}
```

}

It DOESN'T even let me compile.  If I comment out the line mTextView.setText(mText) then it will compile.  Why is .setText() triggering this error?  My goal was to update the TextView from my MainActivity like so:

```
Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
tab1.changeText("Please Update This Text");
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are two possibilities. Either you are calling `changeText()` before `onCreateView()` is called, or else your layout doesn't have a view with id `tabby1`. A stack trace would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @tedhopp Sorry.  Both of my textviews are called myTextView1.  It doesn't let me compile even because of the changeText() error

Comment: If it doesn't compile, how could you possibly be getting a NPE?

Answer (score 0):

onCreate of a Fragment is a lifecycle event and will not be executed when you instantiate your Tab1 with new.

You have to wait until it's created to call changeText.

By:

Give the String as an argument (Bundle and setArguments) so you can get at onCreateView (getArguments().getString(KEY))

OR:

Store it as a variable in changeText and set at onCreate. This approach is a bad pratice since it cannot be reconstructed if needed, loosing it value.

Comment: would you be able to give me some examples. i should mention it doesnt let me compile even due to this line: public void changeText(String mText) {
    mTextView.setText(mText);
}